# Display object name, and add to list

Tags: c#

I have a base class that implements an abstract class. I am
Abstract class;

```
public abstract class Employee
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public abstract void Talk();
        public abstract void Run();
    }
```

Base Class

```
public class SalesPerson : Employee
    {
        public override void Talk()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Talking to Customers");
        }

        public override void Run()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Running after sales");
        }
    }
```

method calling this

```
public void Enter(object employee)
        {
            List<Employee>ShopEmployee= new List<Employee>();
            Console.WriteLine($"{ShopEmployee} has entered the shope");
        }
```

I have done research and I have implement the abstract class and other interface. How to I display the instance of the employee passed and add it to a collection like list.
eg

```
Andrew has entered the shop
Smith has entered the shop
```

Comment: Why the `object employee` parameter? (also why not `Employee` type) Also I didn't understand your question, do you  want the`Enter` method to add an `Employee` to a list?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Since Employee is abstract you can only add objects of type salesperson inte the list of employees.

Answer (score 0):

Since the the employee is passed as `object` you first need to cast the parameter to an `Employee`. You could use [Pattern Matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching) to solve this. Now you are able to add the employee to a list and print it's ID:

```
private readonly List<Employee> shopEmployee = new List<Employee>();
public void Enter(object employee)
{
    if (employee is Employee e)
    {
        shopEmployee.Add(e);
        Console.WriteLine($"{e.Id} has entered the shop");
    }
}
```